# Pixelated Image when using Glide with placeholder

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I use Glide for loading an image file into an ImageView like this:

```
GlideApp.with(this)
        .load(imageURL)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .into(mImageView);
```

Loaded image and placeholder have the same resolution (1920*1200). But if the loaded image is in portrait format and the placeholder in landscape, the loaded image gets stretched and pixelated. These are the size values, I get in Logcat:

```
mImageView.getWidth(): 870
mImageView.getHeight(): 1393
mImageView.getDrawable().getBounds().width(): **339**
mImageView.getDrawable().getBounds().height(): **543**
```

As you can see, the size of the drawable bitmap is much smaller than the size of the imageview.

If both have the same orientation, I get equal sizes and everything looks good.

My questions are:
1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I fix this?

Here's my xml code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```